# arm elf load address 0x8000, EPERM error for non-root user

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

elf file runs successfully when running as root but as non-root it is directly killed due no permission to map address 0x8000.

```
strace /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 --verify ./test
...
mmap2(0x8000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
...
```

is there a way to give the non-root user permission to allow mapping to 0x8000 address?

works after:

`echo 0x8000 > /proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr`

Comment: Why do you think your error has anything to do with the address and not with file descriptor you are using? Non root users may not have execute permission on that file.